# When can a deck be shuffled by shuffling fixed subdecks?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, algorithms

Suppose I want to shuffle a deck of $n$ cards, but I have a problem -- for some reason, I am only able to shuffle at most $n-1$ cards at a time at some fixed indices. For example, if $n=5$, I could choose to shuffle the $k=3<n$ cards at the indices $1, 3, 4$ amongst themselves. Note that the indices must be fixed and chosen in advance (non-random); the only source of randomness is the shuffling. Can I choose a sequence of indices so that the resulting shuffle is uniformly random over all permutations?

We can formalize the question as follows: for which $n$ is it true that there is a sequence of sets of indices $I_1, I_2, \dots I_m \subsetneq [n]$, each a strict subset of $[n]$, such that if we define the random variable $\pi_i$ to be a uniformly random permutation of $[n]$ fixing each element of $[n] \setminus I_i$, then the composition $\pi_1\pi_2\cdots \pi_m$ is a uniformly random permutation of $[n]$?

**Observations**:

1. Since we can shuffle any $n-1$ cards, really all we need to do is insert a single card at  a random index into the deck using shuffling.
2. If $n$ is prime, this is impossible since the number of possibilities for each $\pi_i$ is $|I_i|!$, which is not a multiple of $n$. Thus, the total number of possible choices of permutations is not a multiple of $n$, so each of the $n!$ shuffles cannot be exactly equally likely.
3. For $n=4$, I wrote a quick script which showed that going through the $3$ transpositions in the order $(12), (13), (24)$ and applying each one with probability $1/2$ (i.e. shuffling those two cards) results in $1$ being shuffled evenly. I found this by just playing around/picking randomly, without any real method. Combined with (1), this shows that a size 4 deck can be shuffled by a shuffle on 3 cards, followed by 3 shuffles on 2 cards.

Can every composite-size deck be shuffled uniformly using only strictly smaller shuffles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Let $n = cd$ for some positive integers $1 < c, d < n$. Define
\begin{align*}
I_0 &= [c], \\
I_i &= \{i, i+c, i+2c, \dots, i +(d-1)c\} \quad \forall 1 \leq i \leq c.
\end{align*}
Then, applying $I_0, I_1, \dots, I_c$ in that order will result in the card originally at index $1$ being shuffled evenly.

For example, with $c = 3$ and $d = 4$, the shuffles will be $(\color{red}{1} \: \color{blue}{2} \: \color{green}{3})$, $(\color{red}{1 \: 4 \: 7 \:10})$, $(\color{blue}{2 \: 5 \: 8 \:11})$, $(\color{green}{3 \: 6 \: 9 \:12})$.

The shuffling can perhaps be described in natural language as follows:

1. Divide the $n$ cards into $c$ piles, each containing $d$ cards.
2. Get the topmost card of each pile.
3. Shuffle those $c$ cards.
4. Put back one card in each pile.
5. Shuffle each pile.

This method cannot be used when $n$ is prime because you'll end up shuffling all $n$ cards in either step 3 or step 5.

Answer (score -1):

Even when we have to shuffle 2 cards at a time , we can achieve it easily.

**Algorithm :**
Place the $n$ cards in a circle & number them $1$ to $n$.
Choose $k=n-1$ cards starting @ Position $P_1=1$ , that is $1$ to $n-1$.
Shuffle those $k$ cards.
Select $k=n-1$ cards starting @ Position $P_1=2$ , that is $2$ to $n$.
Shuffle those $k$ cards.
Select $k=n-1$ cards starting @ Position $P_1=3$ , that is $3$ to $n+1$ , where $n+1$ refers to Card 1 by circular arithmetic or modulo arithmetic.
Shuffle those $k$ cards.
Do this for all Starting Positions $P_1=1$ to $P_1=n$ , going over the circle.
Do the whole thing again to go over the Circle , but this time let $P_2$ initiate at $2$ & go around the circle to terminate at $P_2=1$.
Do the whole thing again to go over the Circle , but this time let $P_3$ initiate at $3$ & go around the circle to terminate at $P_3=2$.
Do the whole thing over & over again to go over the Circle , until $P_n$ will initiate at $n$ & go around the circle to terminate at $P_n=n-1$.

**When the algorithm terminates , the cards will be uniformly shuffled , every card being equally likely to be at every Position.**

This works when $k=n-1$ or when $k=\sqrt{n}$ or even ( worst Case ) when $k=2$

**Every time , we shuffle $k$ cards , & terminate with uniformly shuffling $n$ cards.**

**ADDENDUM :**

(1) What Exactly is shuffling $k$ Items ?
**It is the random reordering of those $k$ Items with Equal Probability.**
Eg : What Exactly is shuffling $2$ Items ? It is random reordering of those $2$ Items. In other words , given input $AB$ , output can be $AB$ or $BA$ with Equal ( $1/2$ ) Probability.
Eg : What Exactly is shuffling $3$ Items ? It is random reordering of those $3$ Items. In other words , given input $ABC$ , output can be $ABC$ or $BAC$ or $ACB$ or $CAB$ or $BCA$ or $CBA$ with Equal ( $1/6$ ) Probability.

(2) In the given algorithm , the Index list is pre-chosen & not random.
When we are shuffling the Sub-Set of $k$ Items , we are introducing randomness.
**According to OP , this is the given requirement.**

Comment: I'm not sure if the algorithm will result in a uniform shuffle. Could you elaborate on why? I tried analyzing your algorithm $n = 4$ and $k = 2$, and found that the card at position 1 has probability $256/1024$, $258/1024$, $255/1024$, and $255/1024$ to end up at position 1, 2, 3, and 4 respectively after all $16$ shuffles.

Comment: I was going with Symmetry Arguments , hence , all Arrangements have to be equally likely. Did you Analytically calculate that ? Or was it numerical Simulation ? I will recheck my thinking , @VTand , I will update here later !

Comment: I analytically calculated it. Of course, my calculation could be mistaken. I also numerically simulated it, and did get a less uniform distribution, but only by a bit. I cannot conclude anything confidently from just the simulation.

Comment: -1 for claiming a solution without proof, and without actually checking if it works. @prem

Comment: I agree with your thinking & assessment , but I am not really sure whether this is wrong or unfixable , @MikeEarnest , **Symmetry** suggests that this should work. I will try to update later , maybe 2-3 Days. I am still wondering what is going wrong here.

Comment: You cannot just throw around the word "symmetry" without proof, because it leads to mistakes. In fact, there is no way your method can work, because we know from point (2) in the question post that there is no solution when $n$ is prime, but your method never uses the fact that $n$ is composite. Since there is no hope of rescuing this method, I suggest you delete it.